# Curl error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: php, api, ssl, curl

I have this php code which trying to send get request to Network device

```
$username='restconf-api';
$password='rest.b';

 $apiUrl = 'https://10.10.0.254:1025/restconf/data/ietf-system:system-state?content=all';
     $curl_handle = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);

     curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
     curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
     curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);


     curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);
     curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
 curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:SSLv3');



     curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/yang-data+xml'

));
     $response = curl_exec($curl_handle);

     $content = curl_exec( $curl_handle );
     $err     = curl_errno( $curl_handle );
     $errmsg  = curl_error( $curl_handle );
     $header  = curl_getinfo( $curl_handle );
     curl_close( $curl_handle );

     $header['errno']   = $err;
     $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
     $header['content'] = $content;
    curl_close($curl_handle);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
 $json = json_encode($xml);

$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
     var_dump(  $array);
echo $array['data']['system-state']['system-version'];
```

this code is worked successfully in my first server , but when I tried it in other machine it is not worked  and I just removed this lines and it worked

```
   curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:SSLv3');
```

but when I tried with another machine (all of these machine are ubuntu 18.04 )
 it is not working 
I tried to remove the ubove lines but still get this error

> error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
>   when I add these lines

```
   curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:SSLv3');
```

I get this error

> OpenSSL was built without SSLv3 support

why is that happening, the PHP version is the same in all machine

Comment: PHP may be the same, but OpenSSL is probably not. The manual recommends not to set the `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION` option: [https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php]. "3" as value is considered as dangerous anyway. That means you can't use your cipher list either. So, everything should be fine without these two lines.

Comment: @Mel_T thank you for your reply , Actually I removed these tow lines and try in another machine but get error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Comment: That error can also occur when the certificate is wrong. The CNAME must match exactly the hostname. Use SANs if you need more than one CNAME. Check your certificate with `openssl x509 -noout -text -in certname.crt`.